# issue with xml in ie10

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

```
<XM1L ID="Update"><%= HdrXML.xml %></X1ML>
<script language="Javascript">
    var xslPath = "../Naven.xsl";
    var x = OrchGenericObj.TranformSP(Update.innerHTML,xslPath);
    document.write (x);
</script>
```

I have code like above.  In IE10 Update.innerHTML its giving all the js code including  HdrXML.xml because of this i am not able to load the xml but same code working fine in all other versions of IE...In Other versions when i do the  Update.innerHTML it gives me only HdrXML.`enter code here`xml thats wat i wanted... any idea why such behavoiur in IE10..

Answer (score 1):

The opening tag XM1L does not match your closing tag X1ML.  You should also be using this line:

```
 var x = OrchGenericObj.TranformSP(document.getElementById("Update").innerHTML, xslPath);
```